# How to represent custom object as parameter of an api in swagger-editor

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I want to represent custom object as parameter of an api in swagger-editor. Lets say we are calling an api **/postInfo/data**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postInfo/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Info requestProcessing(@RequestBody Info info)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Above method contains Info model class as a parameter :

```
class Info
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;
}
```

How can this be represented in swagger editor as yaml document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swagger 2.0, object schemas can be defined in the global `definitions` section:

```
definitions:
  Info:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string
      desc:
        type: string
```

and then `$ref`'ed from other parts of the spec.

If an object is used an input for an operation, the operation needs to define a body parameter with a `schema` that corresponds to that object's schema.

```
paths:
  /postInfo/data:
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Info'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```